# Set Search Params into URL triggers Root loader. How do I Prevent this?

Tags: remix.run

I've fetched some shared data in `root.tsx` loader.

When I change search parameters let's say `page`, remix sends two requests. one to root loader and another from the current route. is it expected behavior? how do I prevent re-fetch the root loader request?

```
<Link to={"/shop/category1"}>Category 1</Link>
<Link to={"/shop/category2"}>Category 2</Link> // navigating from category1 to this doesn't re-fetch root loader
<Link to={"/shop/category2?page=2"}>Category 2, page 2</Link> // but re-fetch root loader when navigate to this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `unstable_shouldReload` function in your *root* route.

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/conventions#unstable_shouldreload